# How do i perform i/o operations in PlayN project?

Tags: playn

AssetManager has only getSound() and getImage() methods. I couln't find any Streams realisation of smth that could provide reading/writing other kinds of resources such as binaries and so on.
In what direction should i look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because PlayN supports HTML5 which ultimately compiles to JavaScript, and because JavaScript lacks any sort of streams or binary I/O (at least until the WebGL motivated binary support becomes available in more browsers), PlayN cannot provide any APIs for streams or binary data manipulation.

Your best bet is to use JSON and predefined media formats (like images and sounds).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to getImage and getSound, it also has getText, which you can use to read other kinds of resources (including JSON files). If you're not committed to streams and binary data, GetText may be useful to you.

As far as writing, the Storage API exists for simple key/value pairs, which is sufficient for savegames. I'm not sure if that's what you had in mind.